# Paredit doesn't close {

Tags: paredit

I am using paredit. It terminates `(` and `[` and `"` fine, but does not close the `{` in any modes. How can i configure it to do this too? I have emacs24.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The commands are defined, but not bound to a key by default. You can add them to the paredit map with this:

```el
(eval-after-load 'paredit
  '(progn
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "{")
       'paredit-open-curly)
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "}")
       'paredit-close-curly)))
```

You may prefer to add them to particular programming mode keymaps, rather than the paredit-mode-map; just modify accordingly.